# UIImage wont show on UIView running transformation

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, cgaffinetransform

I have a UIView that runs a transformation to simulate the wobble animation.

There is another UIImageView on top of this UIView that and I set its hidden flag to NO when the animation starts. For some reason the image doesnt show, on rare occasions it does.

Im not sure why this is happening. Maybe the UIView transformation does something to its layers?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [UIView bringSubviewToFront:UIImageView]; ?

Comment: That worked thank you. You could add an answer if you like.

Comment: Thanks. It was weird because the UIImageView would show on random occasion during a gesture on the UIView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the UIImageView be infront of everything in that UIView you are transforming use

`[UIView bringSubviewToFront:UIImageView];`